# D3.js exit().remove() does not remove data/line

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I hava a multi line chart with D3.js.

Initial rendering works just fine. When I try to update, only new lines are added instead of the old ones update/removed.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ty192n93/6/

This is the part where the line is rendered:

```
var node = svg.selectAll(".g.city")
    .data(data, function(d) { return d.name; });

var enter = node.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "city");

enter.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", function(d) {
        return line(d.data);
    })
    .style("stroke", function(d) {
        return color(d.name);
    });
// Text element left out

var remove = node.exit().remove();
```

How is it possible to update the old values (key function is specified) or remove them completely?

Answer (score 1):

Your first selection is wrong. The selector `.g.city` selects all elements having both *classes* `g` and `city`. Your selection is valid, though, but will always return an empty selection putting all your data in the enter selection and leaving the exit selection empty.  Instead, you are interested in group elements `g` having class `city`. Removing the first dot from the selector should do the trick:

```
var node = svg.selectAll("g.city")   // <-- remove the dot
    .data(data, function(d) { return d.name; });
```

Comment: Interesting, sounds good, but after removing the dot, new data is not rendered at all. The old values are also not removed!

Comment: The rest of your code seems to be ok. To get further help, you need to provide more code or even better a live demo to play around with.

Comment: As ists a complex application with a webservice a tried to reduce it to be very simple. This example has the same problem: http://jsfiddle.net/ty192n93/6/